# How to navigate a cursor into my 2D array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array

So I have been trying to find an answer for this since two days now, i'm still a student and I don't know if couldn't understand the other posts, or if my case is too specific to be solved with anything I found on the internet.

As I said in my title I have a 2D array of class called "piece", anytime I start the game it'll create a 2D array with random rows and columns (to explain quickly the goal is to connect all the pieces to win, you rotate the pieces to make the connections). It was going fine with the OnMouseClick(); function but since I need to use the arrows of my keyboard to archieve this, I'm encountering some troubles.

I've got a function which is generating the puzzle each time I start or reset it (So it's called in Start(); and the Update(); when I'm pressing a "clear" button) which is going like this :

```
public piece[,] pieces;
public GameObject Cursor;

void GeneratePuzzle()
    {
        pieces = new piece[width, height];

        int[] auxValues = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
            {
                //width restrictions
                if (w == 0)
                    auxValues[3] = 0;
                else
                    auxValues[3] = pieces[w - 1, h].values[1];

                if (w == width - 1)
                    auxValues[1] = 0;
                else
                    auxValues[1] = Random.Range(0, 2);

                //heigth resctrictions
                if (h == 0)
                    auxValues[2] = 0;
                else
                    auxValues[2] = pieces[w, h - 1].values[0];

                if (h == height - 1)
                    auxValues[0] = 0;
                else
                    auxValues[0] = Random.Range(0, 2);

                //tells piece type
                int valueSum = auxValues[0] + auxValues[1] + auxValues[2] + auxValues[3];

                if (valueSum == 2 && auxValues[0] != auxValues[2])
                    valueSum = 5;

                go = (GameObject)Instantiate(piecesPrefabs[valueSum], new Vector3(origin.position.x + w, origin.position.y, origin.position.z + h), Quaternion.identity);
                go.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;

                while (go.GetComponent<piece>().values[0] != auxValues[0] ||
                      go.GetComponent<piece>().values[1] != auxValues[1] ||
                      go.GetComponent<piece>().values[2] != auxValues[2] ||
                      go.GetComponent<piece>().values[3] != auxValues[3])

                {
                    go.GetComponent<piece>().RotatePiece();
                }
                pieces[w, h] = go.GetComponent<piece>();

                instantiatedPieces.Add(go.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
```

So far I've been trying something like this to make my cursor move in this array :

```
public void Update()
{
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                h++;
                if (h > height)
                    h = 0;
            }
            for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    w++;
                    if (w > width)
                        w = 0;
                }
                // Cursor.transform.position = pieces[w, h].transform.position; ==> I suppose this is where it should be
            }            
        }
}
```

But I end up being out of range or the cursor is so fast I can't see it going over each piece. So to be clear I'd like to be able to move my cursor over each pieces in this 2D array, by row and column (I suppose this is the way to go), after that I'll need to call the function from the piece class for the specific piece my cursor is over but I think I will be able to find this out.

English is not my native language so sorry and I'll try my best if you need any more informations to help me.
Thank you very much any help will be really appreciated !

Comment: You are getting some pretty bad answers, I think its because of the ambiuguity of your question.  So straight out, why are you looping in update?  if you are moving a cursor over elements of the array based off of key input there is no need for a for loop, as you already know the width and height of your array.  I would change it so that in update you have a check if left or right arrow, or up/down arrow, in that check you either increment or decrement the appropriate variable exampe `if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.LeftArow)) { w = mathf.clamp(w-1, 0, width-1); }

Comment: Posted an example as an answer.

Comment: Hello, first thank you for trying to help me. Then, yes, I guess my explanations are not enough accurate. Basically the GeneratePuzzle(); is called once at the start and any time I want to start a new puzzle. So I tried a loop because with the example you gave (and that I'm trying out), "w" and "h" doesn't exist that's maybe why I came up with a loop which fixed that problem but still doesn't give any result. I'm pretty sure there's something here I'm missing, I also tried to play with the existing list in "instantiatedPieces" but it gave nothing really good so far

Comment: I'll need after to be able to call a function from the class piece to rotate it, I can give a screenshot of how it looks like "in game" if it may help to understand.

Comment: To use my example declare your w/h at the outside of the function I will give an example in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of my comment:

If you want to move a cursor over the elements of your array in update based off of keypress, there is no need for a for loop.

```
 // Declared outside of your update makes these class variables that
 // will live as long as this object exists.

 int w = 0; // May be better to change this to cursorXPos
 int h = 0; // May be better to name this cursorYPos

 public void Update()
 {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            w--;
            if (w < 0)
                w = width -1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            w++;
            if (w >= width)
                w = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            h--;
            if (h < 0)
                h = height -1;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            h++;
            if (h >= height)
                h = 0;
        }

        Cursor.transform.position = pieces[w, h].transform.position; 
 }
```

Comment: It worked and I also archieved to rotate the pieces as I wanted ! Thank you so much Eddge for the time you took and your answers !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you're trying to do with your code but.
I don't get what you're using the following line in update for.

```
for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
```

try removing that line.

Comment: hello, thanks for trying to help me out, I don't understand why it should be removed, don't I need to have a index for my width and one for my height to move my cursor in my 2D array called "pieces[,]" ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 public void Update()
 {
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            h++;
            if (h > height)
                h = 0;
        }
     }
     for (int w = 0; w < width; w++)
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
         {
             w++;
             if (w > width)
                 w = 0;
         }
         // Cursor.transform.position = pieces[w, h].transform.position; ==> I suppose this is where it should be
     }            

 }
```

or this:

```
 public void Update()
 {
    for (int h = 0; h < width; h++)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            h++;
            if (h > height)
                h = 0;
        }
     }
     for (int w = 0; w < height; w++)
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
         {
             w++;
             if (w > width)
                 w = 0;
         }
         // Cursor.transform.position = pieces[w, h].transform.position; ==> I suppose this is where it should be
     }            

 }
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I'm still out of range, I think there is also a problem to give the position of the piece to my cursor with this method

Comment: did you try both?

Answer (score 1):

with WindowsForms I would use the KeyDown event and increase/decrease h or w and set them to zero or max when reaching an edge.